# Call Variable from reactive data() in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to call a certain variable within a reactive expression. Something like this:

**server.R**

```
library(raster)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data <- reactive({
inFile <- input$test #Some uploaded ASCII file
asc <- raster(inFile$datapath) #Reads in the ASCII as raster layer

#Some calculations with 'asc':

asc_new1 <- 1/asc
asc_new2 <- asc * 100
})

output$Plot <- renderPlot({

inFile <- input$test
if (is.null(inFile)
 return (plot(data()$asc_new1)) #here I want to call asc_new1
plot(data()$asc_new2)) #here I want to call asc_new2
})
})
```

Unfortunately I could't find out how to call `asc_new1` and `asc_new2` within `data()`. This one doesn't work:

```
data()$asc_new1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reactives are just like other functions in R. You can't do this:

```
f <- function() {
  x <- 1
  y <- 2
}

f()$x
```

So what you're within `output$Plot()` won't work either. You can do what you want by returning a list from `data()`.

```
data <- reactive({

  inFile <- input$test 
  asc <- raster(inFile$datapath) 
  list(asc_new1 = 1/asc, asc_new2 = asc * 100)

})
```

Now you can do:

```
data()$asc_new1
```

Comment: For some reason I still get the same Error. I've putted my variabale into a `list` but I still can't call it: `Error in data()$fitnew : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Comment: Are you definitely putting the `list` on the last line of your `data()` function? This is what will get returned.

Answer (score 0):

"With `data()$asc_new1` you wont be able to access the in the `reactive` context created variables (at least with the current shiny version).
You need `data()[1]` `data()[2]` if you put it in a list like MadScone. Calling it with the `$` sign would raise

> Warning: Unhandled error in observer: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

However, the error your getting

> Error in data()$fitnew : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

is not only because you access the variable wrong. You named the output of your `reactive` function `data` which is reserved name in `R`. You want to change that to `myData` or something.