# Scheduled Updates for Dataset in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a dashboard where I have multiple charts pulling from a single data set, and I would like to refresh that data after a set amount of time. Here is what I have right now, which isn't working:

```
## server.R ##
library(shiny)

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 sourceData <- observe({
    invalidateLater(15000,NULL)
    runif(100, 0, 100)
    })

 output$reactiveHist <- renderPlot({
    hist(sourceData)
  })  

})
```

It seems pretty straight forward, after 15000 ms the observer should run again creating a new data set. However, it generates this error:

```
Error in hist.default(sourceData) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the source of the data in your app? Is it really random numbers or are you pulling in a file from somewhere?

Comment: No, the random numbers are just for example. The actual data is coming from a Redshift database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post: [Call Variable from reactive data() in R Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421779/call-variable-from-reactive-data-in-r-shiny-app?rq=1)

Here is the working code:

```
 library(shiny)

 data <- reactive({
   invalidateLater(5000,NULL)
   list(unif = runif(100, 0, 100), norm = rnorm(100, 0, 100))
 }) 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$reactiveHist <- renderText({
    paste(data()$unif)
  })  

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `reactiveFileReader()` function. It basically reads in a data source and makes it reactive. You can specify a interval in milliseconds and the application will check the source on that interval and upload it again if it has changed. You can also specify the path to the source and the function used to read in the source, so a wide variety of sources can be read in.

Comment: reactiveFileReader() has to read a file, correct? If I'm using a function to create data (such as a database query), will it still work?

Comment: The function needs a path to your data, and a command to read in your data that takes the path as the first augment and the will accept any other arguments you need. So you could give it the path to your database, the command used to read the database and then the query or whatever else you need to read the data. If you are having a problem getting that to work you could probably post it as a separate question and get it sorted out.