# How to refer to variable of dataset in reactivity

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm making a Shiny app. I use reactivity programming for better fuctionality. But I don't know how to refer to dataset that is reactive object. Here is the example:

```
buffer_bank <- reactive({mydata <-
        merge(buffer_data(), rwa())%>%
        mutate(buff = case_when(REGN %in% (szko$REGN) ~ (buffer + buffer_szko), TRUE ~ buffer))%>%
        select(REGN, buff)
    mydata})
```

Where `buffer_data()` and `rwa()` are reactive objects that is why I passed `()` after datasets in both cases. But how to refer to `REGN` variable in `szko` dataset, which is reactive object too.

How can I handle this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421779/call-variable-from-reactive-data-in-r-shiny-app

Comment: @A.Suliman I.ve read the post, but unfortunately I don't understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: @DavidBijoyan, would it be possible to generate a complete reproducible example? What does your `szko` reactive statement look like? What does `szko()$REGN` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. The solution is to put `()` in `szko()$REGN` statement. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. usually, I'll do a normal assign inside `renderTable` e.g `df <- dat()`, then I use `df` as usual, but I think you have different requirements.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("4" = "4",
                  "6" = "6",
                  "8" = "8")),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    dat <- reactive({
      list(mt=mtcars)
    })

    output$data <- renderTable({
      #browser()
      dat()$mt[dat()$mt$cyl %in% input$variable, ]
      #2nd option given that you defined reactive using dat <- reactive({mtcars})
      #df <- dat()
      #df[df$cyl %in% input$variable, ]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }
)
```